# Unable to extend ubuntu /home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory, lts

I am new to ubuntu (Ubuntu LTS 20.1) and had installed it when Windows 10 is pre-installed.
These are some screenshots from the "Disks" app in ubuntu.

Partitions available - see free space 26 GB

[image: img_Partitions_available]

Unable to resize the home partition using free space

[image: img_resize]

I don't have a backup to my windows/ubuntu files and I want to extend my /home partition in a safe way.
I went through many other similar questions but they are not detailed enough for me to go forward safely or they are not of updated version of ubuntu lts.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed with this question. Are you asking which partitions to shrink so that you can grow the partition used by `/home`? 

Comment: @Matigo I want to extend my /home partition. I want to use the free space that I made through shrinking my windows partition (did in windows).

Comment: You have to move the partition#4 to the left first to make the free space adjecant to the partition you want to resize (which I guess is partition#5). You have to do all this from a live session, you can not do it while booted into your installation since the partitions are mounted and you can't edit (move,resize) mounted partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always some risk to your data if you resize partitions so backup anything you cannot afford to lose.

To resize your /home partition you need to do the following:

1. Using your install media boot into the live environment (Try Ubuntu)
2. Using GParted move your root partition all the way to the left, into the unused space. This effectively moves the unused space to the right of the root partition.
3. Using GParted resize your home partition making use of the unused space which is now to the left of the home partition.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Ponjar. Can you please explain how to boot into live environment? I did do live boot but that was when I am installing ubuntu. Now, I need to keep my ubuntu the same and extend partition. I didn't understand what is live booting when I already have my ubuntu installed.

Comment: You use the same install media that you used to install Ubuntu but when you get to the screen that gives you two options to either “Install Ubuntu” or “Try Ubuntu” you choose “Try Ubuntu”. That will take you into what looks like a normal Ubuntu desktop. From there you can use GParted to work on your partitions